# How to write this sqlcmd command without quotes?

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a .bat file that is executing a sql server stored procedure. It is working great when I launch it manually (double clicking the bat file) but it is not working when I schedule it with a windows task. I read that the windows task scheduler doesn't like double quotes. So that is worth a try but I do not see how to write this command without the double quotes:

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\SRVER1 -d MYDB -Q "EXEC dbo.master"
```

Comment: Try to start the bat file by the task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

You can write your command : `EXEC dbo.master` in a .sql file and then you call this file.

for exemple:

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\SRVER1 -d MYDB -i C:\test\test.sql
```